# Reading and Writing to an Excel file in Resources

Tags: excel, vb.net

I've added my excel file as a resource to my vb project and used the "embedded Resource" option. The name of the file "StoredInformation.xlsx". 
The 'Build Action' is set to 'Embedded Resource'.

Edit II - However i'm quite stuck again. It seems as if my code doesnt even work when i run my program

```
Dim sPath As String

    sPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments))

    For i = 1 To 50
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        Application.DoEvents()

    Next

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(sPath & "\Housing\Stored Information.xlsx") Then
        Dim APP As New Excel.Application
        workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\Housing\Stored Information.xlsx")
        worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        APP.Visible = False
        MessageBox.Show("File Opened!" & Environment.NewLine & "Path: " & sPath & "\Housing\Stored Information.xlsx")
    Else
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(sPath & "\Housing\Stored Information.xlsx", My.Resources.StoredInformation, True)
        Dim APP As New Excel.Application
        workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\Housing\Stored Information.xlsx")
        worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        APP.Visible = False
        MessageBox.Show("File Created!" & Environment.NewLine & "Path: " & sPath & "\Housing\Stored Information.xlsx")
    End If
```

It's not creating my folder "Housing" or my file "Stored Information.xlsx"
Could someone please take a look and tell me what im doing wrong?

Edit - I found out that it can't create the new dir because of the protection level, so when i changed the destination to the desktop it created the excel file, but it needed to be repaired.

Can someone tell me how to created a new folder and add a file without damaging the excel file?

Edit - Made changes to the code, it's still not creating the new folder in My Documents and add the file "Stored Information.xlsx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Unraveling the confusion about Embedded Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8851991/6922376) - Found this thread

Explains how to embed resources that you use for your program and how to access it. It deffinetly helped me

Edit: Answer

```
Dim sPath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "Housing")

    Dim Fpath As String = sPath & "\Stored Information.xlsx"

    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(sPath) ' If location already exists it will not do anything

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Fpath) = False Then
       My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(Fpath, My.Resources.StoredInformation, True) ' Don't want to append data (although that would not happen in this instance) so True is used for that.
    End If

    Dim APP As New Excel.Application
    workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open(Fpath)
    worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    APP.Visible = False
    MessageBox.Show("File Opened!" & Environment.NewLine & "Path: " & Fpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

For reading and writing to an excel file I would look into this older post I found that lists a few libraries and resources for interacting with excel files.

[Excel Library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5858361/4962223)

[More Excel Libraries](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/Excel)

Comment: Was a helpful reference, but the answers were for C#, im looking for Vb.net codes

Comment: Still not what im looking for